# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'

Tags: apt, python, python3

After some manipulations with updating Python to version 3.9 and using the command "python" to invoke Python 3.9 (update-alternatives), or perhaps something else, I encountered a global issue, every update/install/reinstall etc is:

```
Setting up python-wheel (0.29.0-2) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: error processing package python-wheel (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pkg-resources (33.1.1-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: error processing package python-pkg-resources (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-pip (18.1-5) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: error processing package python-pip (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up python-xdg (0.25-4+deb9u1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile", line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version import SUPPORTED, debsorted, vrepr, \
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'debpython'
dpkg: error processing package python-xdg (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-setuptools:
 python-setuptools depends on python-pkg-resources (= 33.1.1-1); however:
  Package python-pkg-resources is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-setuptools (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-wheel
 python-pkg-resources
 python-pip
 python-xdg
 python-setuptools
```

I can install or uninstall packages, update, or do something else. However, all of my scripts have stopped working. Unfortunately, I couldn't find a solution to my problem on the internet. I have already tried everything I could find regarding my issue.

Comment: Updating the system Python in Debian, Ubuntu or the like is a bad idea. Just don't. If you still have the original system Python packages installed, undo your `update-alternatives` change to make `/usr/bin/python` etc. point to those instead.

Comment: @muru 
Of course, I have already tried resetting to the default version 2.7. Unfortunately, the result is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Debian 9 expects `python` to be a link to the Python 2 interpreter; as you discovered, you can’t change that without breaking parts of the system (if you have Python 2 modules installed).

You need to undo whatever you did with `update-alternatives` — many web sites suggest using that with Python installations, but the Python packages in Debian don’t use `update-alternatives` — and restore the `python` symlink:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python
```

If you can upgrade to Debian 11, that would give you the Debian Python 3.9 package (as well as a supported release).